# Twitterのrequest_tokenでiOSのTwitterアプリがある場合、そちらのSchemeを使ってやる場合の方法はどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, twitter

通常Twitterでrequest_tokenをする場合、ブラウザ経由でログインしてサードパティに許可を与えるなどをすると思うのですが、iOSだとアプリ経由で出来る方法があるようです。これの方法がドキュメントを探してもわからなかったため、質問させていただきました。

[feather](https://apps.apple.com/jp/app/feather-for-twitter/id793157344), [Hel2um](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrDJB.jpg)などはそれを採用しています。

アプリ経由だと以下スクショのようになります。

[image]

Comment: おそらく以下リンクのように`twitterauth://authorize?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=zzz&oauth_callback=yyy-xxx
`といった形で出来るようです。帰ったら試してみます。
https://twittercommunity.com/t/ios-correct-url-for-in-app-authorization/136697

Comment: TwitterのライブラリSwifterにもこの記述がありました。

https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter/blob/50682ebe64e4c08f18957ccfd16888f035c20755/Sources/SwifterAuth.swift#L161

Comment: 試してみましたが、なぜかoauth_callbackクエリなしでいくとTwitter画面で認証画面が開き、oauth_callbackクエリありだと認証画面に遷移しません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swifterにもアプリ経由での認証できる関数が用意されていますが、これはtwitter-kitがサポートされていたころの名残で利用できていたようです。現在も公にはサポートされていないですが、その機能自体は残っているようです。

なのでtwitter-kitと同じやり方をすればうまくいくようです。
しかしURL Schemeにconsumer_keyを使用するという形で、そのconsumer_keyは簡単に閲覧可能なので、使用するのは危険とみなし、実装をやめることにしました。

### 基本的なやり方

自分はうまくいきませんでしたが、以下の方法でうまくいくはずです。

- 自分のURL Schemeに`twitterkit-\(consumer_key)`を設定
- 以下URLにアクセス

`twitterauth://authorize?consumer_key=\(consumerKey)&consumer_secret=\(consumerSecret)&oauth_callback=twitterkit-\(consumerKey)`